# Tesseract OCR fails recognizing simple numbers

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm rather new to Python but already running into a brick wall.
I'm trying to use OCR on very simple numbers. They pop  up on screen and sare supposed to be read by OCR and then paste them in a cvs file. Everything works except OCR.

It does sometimes work but if you look at the two pictures the one number gets detected, the other doesn't. Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone got an idea on how to improve it? Can I maybe use something else instead of OCR Image Recognition for my project?

[image: number can't get recognized]

[image: number can get recognized]

Here's my code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

screenshot = Image.open("test_image.png")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(screenshot)

print("Recognized Text:", text)
```

---

- btw, I use the full path to the tesseract executable because otherwise it cant seem to find it anywhere.
- image format is PNG

I tried resizing, changing the font, established high contrast and tried lower contrast.Tried it on many different examples, each one scoring inconsistently.

It resulted in not working or working inconsistently.

Comment: did you try using a different psm? See the details here : https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/11/15/tesseract-page-segmentation-modes-psms-explained-how-to-improve-your-ocr-accuracy/

Comment: Actually worked, thank you so much! Also that article is gold for anyone using OCR. Made my day, thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 0):

See PSM comment indeed.

You also must take care of binarisation.
Your image is white on black. Default binarisation expects black on white.

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(255-np.asarray(screenshot)[...,0], config='--psm 8').strip()
```

Should work fine

`np.asarray(screenshot)` get the image in a form of an array.

Since your image is RGB (RGBA even), we want to turn it grayscale first. That is what `np.asarray(screenshot)[...,0]` does (that is, get only red level. Would work also with green and blue, that is `...,1` and `...,2`. Just, don't use `...,3`, that is alpha channel, since it is all 255.
With more colored images, turning a color image to a visible black&white image may be tricker. But here, it doesn't matter. Your image is obviously made of (0,0,0,255) black and (255,255,255,255) white.

Then, we need to turn it black on white, that is reverse values: `255-np.asarray(screenshot)[...,0]`

And that you can pass to tesseract. With the correct psm indeed. Here `8` to choose a psm expecting a single word.

`.strip()` remove control chars.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I forgot to mention that I had already tried inverting the image and then running it through OCR: without any success. But I found the solution because of another commenter that told me to check out PSM. Works like a charme. But thanks for your tips on binarisation, I'll keep that in mind. Love this community. :)

Comment: I saw the comment. It is a very important one indeed. But you need both. At least, on my computer, it is that plain an simple: if you use `psm 8` directly on white-on-black `screenshot`, it doesn't work. If you use default psm on an inverted black-on-white image, it doesn't work neither. You need both, invert and psm 8, to work on this image. Generally speaking it is important when using tesseract 1. to choose correctly PSM (that is the reason for 99% of the "tesseract doesn't work" questions on [so]) 2. to binarize (9% of "tesseract doesn't work"). In your case it is both.